# How come I can't climb the sewer's grids in Fez?

Tags: fez

In the sewers hell, in the room where you turn the valve and start the lava flowing upwards, I got stuck due to some of the climbing grids not being climbable.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

From the OP's answer, originally posted in the question:

> When I encountered this, the fix was to restart the game, it worked after that.